# Constant squeaking when pedalling

Tags: maintenance, chain, noise

My bike has had an ongoing issue for a couple of months. Most of the time I pedal there is a constant squeaking noise (which I can't pinpoint but seems to be from the chain). This noise only occurs when I'm cycling on the big chainring and completely disappears when I cycle on the small chainring. The noise came back even after I got my bike serviced and changed chain (for general maintenance). The only solution I've found is to wet the chain with a hose before cycling but even then the noise will come back after an hour or so and it's obviously very bad for the chain anyway.

If anyone has any solutions they would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is it really a *constant* squeak or does it come and go as the pedals turn?

Comment: Consider that when you're on the big chainring the rear derailer is pulled tighter.  Of course, on the big ring the chain is also way to the outside, such that it might be rubbing on the front derailer.

Comment: Does the squeaking occur also when you backpedal? Also how does it change when you ride on different rear cogs? Maybe some derailer(s) adjustments would solve the issue.

Comment: Or maybe the chain is not designed for the number of gears you have.

Comment: Anyway, I think some amount of noise from the chain is normal. No chain is absolutely silent.

Comment: Daniel, it’s constant very high pitched squeaking but only when pedalling. I suspected the front derailleur too but it’s not making contact with it.

Comment: Robert doesn’t occur when I backpedal but that might be due to putting less force on the chain. It pretty much squeaks on all the cogs I use on the big chainring but nothing on the small chainring. I know chains usually make some noise but this is very much not normal, I also got it fitted by a cycling shop so I don’t think it’s the length

Comment: Does it squeak only when you are riding? When the rear wheel is lifted in the air, and you spin the pedals (on the big chainring), does it still squeak? Or when you're riding at greater speed, and pedalling becomes easier even on the big chainring, less stress being put on the chain, does it still squeak?

Comment: A similar problem: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/14344/32314

Comment: Park Tool has an article about noisy drivetrain: https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/troubleshooting-a-noisy-drivetrain

Comment: Thank you Robert I finally resolved the problem. Ceramic lube did wonders

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason why is your chain squeaking is because there is none or not enough lube on your bike. apply some lube on your chain one drop per rivet and wipe the access lube off (You can choose not to wipe the access lube but it will attract dirt & dust.). A chain with no lube will wear much faster than a chain that is lubed, and it will rust easily too.

Comment: Concur - water makes the noise go away, because water is acting as a lube.  Perhaps the new chain is just as dry as the old one?  Or it may be squeaking as the chain touches the chainring teeth.

Comment: That’s what I think it is as well, but I’ve tried putting lube and the problem is only resolved for about 20 minutes then the noise slowly comes back. Maybe I’m not putting enough but I’m still doing 3 full turns of the chain.

Comment: Try to listen closely, is the sound coming from the front or the back?

Comment: It's very hard to tell but I think the back

Comment: By that, I mean  is the squeaking coming from the bottom bracket or the cassette/derailleur.

Comment: Seems to be the cassette

Comment: Try cleaning your chain and relube it. I don't know if it works but it works for me

Comment: Your advice about lubricating chains is good but I don't see how it could be the answer to the question. Why would a dry chain squeak on the big chainring but not the small one?

Comment: Yeah David it’s a mystery really. I tried putting a lot of lube today and it was significantly less noisy so maybe it really is a matter of changing lube